# Datagridview click error

Tags: c#, datagridview

Sometimes when I click on the row in my datagridview it does not make the code I have written. In other words, there are times when I need to click 2 or 3 times to do what I need.

[This is the code I have when I click on the datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEgzW.png)

[This is my datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExIKJ.png)

[These are the properties of my datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayWgM.png)

Comment: this is what breakpoints are for

Comment: It could possibly be because the click event is trapped by the editable cell and not propagated to the row. Try making it non-editable, or set the selection to FullRowSelect

Comment: I am guessing that you may not be clicking onto the “Content” of the cell. Example let us say you have a text box cell such that the text only fills the cell half way. If you click into a portion of the cell that does not have text beneath the mouse arrow… the `CellContentClick` event wont fire, however, If you click onto the “text” in the cell… it will fire every time.

Comment: @CarloBos This is no longer editable, and the selection is already in FullRowSelect

Comment: JohnG is right; you use the wrong event. Try `CellMouseClick` instead!